# Inseting a calendar into an html file

Tags: html, css, calendar

I want to insert a calendar box in html.

[image]

I found this code after inspected the precised calendar box

```
span.calSel {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #3279c3 url(../images/calendar-icon.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    font: 0/0 a;
    color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But from my understanding, this is only inserting this image:

[image]

not the functionality of clicking on that image and popping a calendar where you can select a date and it will be filled automatically in the date section.

Do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: I'd recommend using a library such as [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) which is pretty easy to use and adds exactly the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: you will find many examples on the internet. i would take an example from bootstrap. here is a link with instructions:
[http://datainflow.com/create-bootstrap-datepicker-html/](http://datainflow.com/create-bootstrap-datepicker-html/) hope this link helps you